# Cordova for iOS loads white page with Gap://ready iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

After updating to Cordova iOS v3.8.0 (included with the latest Cordova 5.1 release), I noticed that my application would start up with a white screen.  I also did not receive the usual javascript console output.  I wasn't sure why until I looked at the DOM tree.  There was only one iFrame, and it was a 'gap://ready' iframe.  I did a little searching and it appears that at least one bug somewhat related to this has appeared before.
This may help provide more clues to diagnose this problem.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8002.

I attempted to update to version 3.9.0 as well, but no luck.  Still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello if you have to load cordova earlier version then i also help you

```
 1. Try this for windows
```

**npm uninstall -g cordova**

```
 2. Try this for MAC
```

**sudo npm uninstall -g cordova**

### And You Can Also Added Cordova Previous Versions Like This

```
3. Install Cordova Previous Versions As bellow command.
```

Cordova is installed using the Node Package Manager (npm). Type the following in the command window to install:

**npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13**

```
4. Install Cordova LATEST VERSION Then Fire As bellow command.
```

**npm install cordova without the -g**

Enjoy ...!!!

Comment: Well, I was hoping to not have to go back to an earlier version, but that may be what I have to do.  Thanks for reminding me that sometimes downgrading is the best fix!

Answer (score -1):

In situations like that I've found its easiest to try

```
cordova platforms rm ios
```

Then

```
cordova platform add ios
```

You can replace iOS with different os name

If that doesn't work you might try making a test app with all the same plugins.

Comment: Unfortunately my app is not in a place where that will be easy to do.  I'll have to add a lot of extra code and components back into my app.  I think downgrading Cordova might be the quickest solution for now.

Comment: It can be difficult. I was thinking more for running an empty phone gap app just to test that it does load the plugins. In my experience it can help expose a smaller issue. How does your config.xml file look? it might be a conflict of the config file telling it to do something you don't want or doing upgrade it didn't merge correctly.

Comment: also it sounds like an event either not firing or firing at a bad time where it's not caught. are you using a framwork with your app?

Comment: Yes, I just switched from Sencha Touch to Ext JS 6.